# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'casper.done()') error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape the href attribute value from all the video links on youtube page after I pass a search query.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var links;

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('div#contents div#dismissable a#thumbnail');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}

casper.start('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=a');

casper.then(function () {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function () {
    for(var i in links) {
        console.log(links[i]);
    }
    casper.done();
});
```

Also is

```
 div#contents div#dismissable a#thumbnail
```

the correct path to scrape the href attribute of each a tag of the video.

when i run this code i get an error saying

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'casper.done()')
>
> C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/scraping codes/phantomjs:/code/test.js:24
>
> C:/Users/rohit/Desktop/scraping codes/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:423 in checkStep

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this line:

```
casper.then(function () {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});
```

Should be

```
casper.then(function () {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks());
});
```

or

```
casper.then(function () {
    links = this.evaluate(function(){
        getLinks();
    });
});
```

Comment: You're wrong unfortunately — this is the way to pass a function for later execution. `this.evaluate(getLinks());` executes `getLinks` immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`casper.done();` is obsolete and is not necessary in scripts anymore, see [the issue](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/1869), just remove it from the script.